# Fail to perfom static registration of nomount instance

Tags: oracle, listener, standby, tnsnames

I'm trying to make standby to database.
I've insalled Oracle 11g database on virtual machine (host - `oratest`). Standby is on virtual machine too (`standbysrv`).

When I'm trying to connect from source database to auxiliary database I'm getting [ORA-12528](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/SearchDocDisplay?_adf.ctrl-state=3ustj4rt4_62&_afrLoop=39334583421332#SYMPTOM).
The only way I can connect to auxiliary databse is using the 2nd method from the note:

```
[oravis@standbysrv backup]$ rman target sys/manager@testprod auxiliary /
Recovery Manager: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Sat Dec 26 19:36:39 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

connected to target database: TEST (DBID=2197628678)
connected to auxiliary database: TEST (not mounted)
```

But this way does not work for active duplicate.

Here is `listener.ora` of source database:

```
    TESTSTAN =
     (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = standbysrv)(PORT = 1521))
     )
     (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = teststan) ) )
```

`listener.ora` of future standby:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
(SID_LIST =
 (SID_DESC =
        (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
        (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oravis/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1)
        (PROGRAM = extproc) )
 (SID_DESC =
        (GLOBAL_DBNAME = teststan)
        (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oravis/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1)
        (SID_NAME = test) ) )

LISTENER =
 (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
 (DESCRIPTION =
 (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = standbysrv)(PORT = 1521))
 (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC0)) ) )
```

Comment: Post the output of `lsnrctl status` from the standby machine. You should see a service called `teststan` with an instance status `UNKNOWN`.

Comment: `teststan` has status `BLOCKED` because it is in nomount mode.

`Instance "teststan", status BLOCKED, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully`

Comment: @BalazsPapp to perfrom duplication a standy database has to be in nomount mode. I've execute `duplicate target database for standby nofilenamecheck dorecover;` just for fun, and now I can mount database, but it has no any sense, because databse should be in nomount state.

Comment: I am well aware of that. And the output clearly shows you did not perform all the steps for static registration, because in addition to the `BLOCKED` entry, there should be another one, labelled `UNKNOWN`. So, did you reload/restart the listener after adding the entries in `listener.ora`?

Comment: @BalazsPapp of course I did.